# Getting Value from JSON Array PHP Nest Arrays

Tags: php, json

I don't know why I can't get this to work so Im sorry for what is probably an easy answer. All I am trying to do is get the value from an array (JSON).

```
 array(1) {
  ["Borrowers"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Full_Name"]=>
      string(18) "Mike Blake"
      ["Email"]=>
      string(18) "adljf@gmail.com"
      ["Address"]=>
      string(36) "Granby Ct., Aurora, CO, 80012"
      ["Position"]=>
      string(8) "Borrower"
      ["ID"]=>
      string(19) "1159827000004784102"
      ["Mobile"]=>
      string(12) "+1303363658"
      ["Application"]=>
      string(35) "Application 1 - 1159827000004784096"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["Full_Name"]=>
      string(18) "Jennifer H Smith"
      ["Email"]=>
      string(25) "js@gmail.com"
      ["Address"]=>
      string(13) "Granby, 80012"
      ["Position"]=>
      string(11) "Co-Borrower"
      ["ID"]=>
      string(19) "1159827000004784108"
      ["Mobile"]=>
      string(12) "+13035235555"
      ["Application"]=>
      string(35) "Application 1 - 1159827000004784096"
    }
  }
}
```

and I am trying to get a value with and without looping.

```
echo $array['Borrowers'][0]['Full_Name'];
```

But the above is not working. Also looking for the foreach version. Thanks.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: did you `decode` your `json` before call ?

Comment: @Barmar. Youre right it did. I love my var_dump in the code and it was throwing an error. When i deleted it, then the echo worked. Thanks and sorry to waste time.

Answer (score 1):

If what you posted is the result of `var_dump($array);` then the code you wrote should work. The loop would be:

```
foreach ($array['Borrowers'] as $borrower) {
    echo $borrower['Full_Name'];
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks.